# Nested IF Statement with Odd / Even

Tags: python

I'm very much new to Python and have been trying out new exercises online and I've completed a few with If/Else/Else If.

This new program I'm trying to run asks the user to enter an integer and depending on what they enter the print feedback will be different. The program must us a Nested IF.

The first statement for 'entered is zero' is working perfectly. But when I enter an even number it still says 'Odd' and I can't work out why and I've been looking at many different tutorials.

Perhaps I'm not using the Nested If Statement in the correct manner?

All help very appreciated.

Thanks!

```
enter = int(input("Enter an Integer: "))
option = enter % 2
if (enter == 0):
  print("The number you entered is zero")
  if (option % 2) > 0:
  print("The number you entered is larger than zero and even")
else:
  print("The number you entered is larger than zero and odd")
```

Comment: Can you make sure the indentation of the code you posted is identical to the one in the original file?

Comment: `option` is the value that determines if `enter` was even or odd; you don't need to divide *it* by 2. Just check if it is 0 or 1.

Comment: You are taking the modulus of the number twice, why? Also, your logic is wrong, if `num % 2 > 0` then `num` is odd, not even.

Answer (score 2):

Since, you specifically asked for `nested if statements`, check the answer below:

```
enter = int(input("Enter an Integer: "))

if enter > 0:
    if enter % 2 == 0:
        print ("Number entered is greater than 0 and even")
    else:
        print ("Number enetred is greater than 0 and odd")
else:
    print ("Number entered is less than or equal to 0")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input("Enter an Integer: "))

if (x >= 0):
  if (x ==0) :
    print("Number is 0" %x)
  elif (x %2 == 0):
    print (" Number %d is a positive even number" %x)
  else:
    print ("Number %d is a positive odd number" %x)
else:
  if (abs(x)%2 == 0):
    print ( "Number %d is a negative even number" %x)
  else:
    print ( "Number %d is a negative odd number" %x)
```